# The error message is the same: "The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server terminated the process"

Tags: jmeter, azure-pipelines, jmeter-plugins

i test using jmeter for load testing with plugins.the The error message is the same: "The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server terminated the process".

Comment: Please provide as much detail as possible in your question. You've provided absolutely no information that can be used to assist you in troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check whether the website returns "the same" error when you access it manually using your web browser. If it doesn't it means that your JMeter script setup is wrong and you need to [configure JMeter to behave like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser)
2. Check whether the website returns "the same" error when you run your test with less threads (virtual users). If it doesn't it means that your website is overloaded and you need to [identify and fix the bottleneck](https://www.educative.io/blog/performance-testing-101-bottlenecks).
3. In the majority of cases you cannot just replay the recorded test script without prior [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) of dynamic parameters so make sure to implement it as well and verify that your JMeter test is doing what it is supposed to be doing by running it with 1-2 users/iterations and inspecting requests and responses using [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener prior to kicking off a full-scale test in the Azure pipelines.